# A trouble with python 'self' argument in functions

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, arguments

This is the code for a simple test:

```
class ECollector:
    #error msg collector
    #this class should be used as 'global'
    msgs = []
    def addmsg(self,msg):
        self.msgs.append(msg)
    def clear(self):
        self.msgs = []

class test(ECollector):
    dcodes = []
    ECollector
    def new(self):
        ECollector.addmsg("test!")
```

And this is what I ran on the python console
(BTW, I'm using pyscripter 2.3 and Python 3.12)

```
>>>a = test()
>>>a.new()
```

and the following is what I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\...\test.py", line 14, in new
    ECollector.addmsg("test!")
TypeError: addmsg() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (1 given)
```

I'm a newbie to python...and I'm rather confused about this whole thing;;;
I thought the 'self' argument is something you don't need to fill-up when calling a def function.

Please rescue this poor newbie from this troublesome 'phenomenon' by giving him solutions.
Thank you :)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by putting `ECollector` on the second line of the definition of `test`? Currently, it does absolutely nothing at all.

Answer (score 3):

You have defined `addmsg` to be an instance method. You probably meant `self.addmsg("test!")` instead of `ECollector.addmsg("test!")`.

Answer (score 2):

There's lots of things that might be wrong with this.  lets start at the top.  It looks like you are really just using `ECollector` as a namespace to group some functions.  That's ok, but you want to make a call to `ECollector.some_method` you need to change things around a bit, by making those methods into class methods:

```
class ECollector:
    """error msg collector
    this class should be used as 'global'"""

    msgs = []

    @classmethod
    def addmsg(cls,msg):
        cls.msgs.append(msg)

    @classmethod
    def clear(cls):
        cls.msgs = []
```

This means that any time you invoke `addmsg` or `clear`, they get an implicit first argument of the class itself.  In this particular way that i've converted it, each subclass will get its own `msgs`.  If you want all of the subclasses to share a single `msgs` attribute, then you can change `cls` to `ECollector`

Also, you will want to change your subclass around just a little bit, because you are subclassing from `ECollector`, but then calling its methods directly.  You can do this instead:

```
class test(ECollector):
    dcodes = []
    def new(self):
        self.addmsg("test!")
```

Comment: Thank you :) I thought it was a python bug;;;

Answer (score 1):

The way in which you are calling `ECollector.addMsg` looks like you're using it as a python static method, which means it won't pass through a "self" parameter (let me know if you're a newcomer to programming languages in general and don't understand what a static method is). However, my guess is that you want to use it as an instance method rather than as a static method.

Instead, you probably want to do it as follows:

```
self.addmsg("test!")
```